# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException after upgrading to Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

After upgrading my Spring MVC application to Spring 3.2 I'm getting the following exception when accessing some of my URLs:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:203) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:272) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:212) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:55) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1091) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1076) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:896) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
(...)
```

This exception results to a HTTP 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE.

I've managed to create a simplified controller with a URL I cannot access:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resources/foo.js", produces = "text/javascript")
@ResponseBody
public String foo() throws Exception {
    return "";
}
```

As I'm using a normal browser which has `*/*` in the `Accept`-header, I don't see why I should get a HTTP 406. What makes this even more strange is that this code is working with Spring 3.1.2, but not with Spring 3.2. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There have been several changes related to how [Spring does content-negotiations in 3.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html#new-in-3.2-webmvc-content-negotiation). One of these changes is that content negotiations can now be done based on the file suffix in the URL. This feature is enabled by default. In Spring versions prior to 3.2 the HTTP accept-header were used for content-negotiations. When browsers accessed your URLs  content-negotiation was seldom an issue, as browser always sends `Accept:(...)*/*`.

Spring has a map of suffix => Media type. For ".js" the default media type is "application/x-javascript". When Spring tries to lookup the handler mapping for a request to /resources/foo.js, it won't match your `foo()`-method as it produces the wrong media type.

I'm not sure if the Spring team has thought through this case. It is at least a bit strange that it lets you create a `@RequestMapping` which cannot be accessed (because of the incompatibility between the .js-media type and what is set in the produces field).

There are several ways of fixing this issue. One is to change the produces-parameter to "application/x-javascript". Another would be to change the media type of ".js" to "text/javascript" ([see the docs of how to do that](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation)). A third possibility is to turn off content-negotiations based on suffixes (again, [see the docs of how to do it](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation)).

Answer (score 2):

I've now got it working by disabling the getting of media type based on the extension of the requested path. This can be done by the following:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"/>
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back to looking at the Accept headers -->
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

And specify version 3.2 for all the xsd schema locations.

Comment: If using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter try 

@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation (ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
 super.configureContentNegotiation(configurer);
 configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a proper `MessageConverter` to your configuration, along with one you might already have for Jackson.

e.g. in your subclass of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
}
```

When you still keep the `favorPathExtension` option turned on, you won't require a `produces` parameter as well, your controller will return `application/javascript`.

The hints in Aleksanders answer actually did not help me getting rid of the 406 when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where rest call to the controller is having path variable which contains .au in path value.
Spring is reading .au as file extention due to spring Content Negotiation

**REST GET call is** 
http://localhost:8080/api/forgot-password/kk@kudeta.com.au
due to .au in path variable Spring is throwing org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

We have resolved it by turning off content based negotiation

```
@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(final 
     ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        // Turn off suffix-based content negotiation
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

}
```