# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException during jQuery ajax call after upgraded to spring 3.2.4

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, maven, jackson

I am getting `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` when making a jQuery ajax call.

I have the following configuration.

In context I have (this is in classpath)

```
<context:component-scan base-package=" group package" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and I have in servlet-config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller pacakges alone" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I have added `jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13` in the pom.xml and using `spring core 3.2.4` and `security 3.1.4`

I have a jQuery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url : "checkUser.html",
    cache : false,
    type : "post",
    data : "email=" + $('#email').val(),
    success : function(response) {
        success callback;
    }
});
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alas i got it , the spring 3.2 version made below change to Configuring Content Negotiation caused the issue ,since content negotiation done by through file extensions by default , my pages stopped working upon upgrading to 3.2 version.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation

i have disable above file media type extension

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this post for more info.

[HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException after upgrading to Spring 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896286/httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-after-upgrading-to-spring-3-2)

Answer (score 2):

This is a better explanation : http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

You might want to set acceptable mediaTypes like :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
  <map>
    <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
    <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
  </map>
 </property>
```

Further you could simply send parameters like

```
var url = "/checkUser/" + $('#email').val() + ".htm";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function(msg){
```

in the Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkUser/{email}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```